# How can i change the Installation Folder Url and Update location of a c# click once application in user machine

Tags: wpf, clickonce

we have a WPF application where we use click once for deployment and installation location is network path, Now we are planning to move it to IIS(http://example.com)
we don't want to inform the existing users to uninstall the application. Is there any possible way to change the installation location and Update location of click once in user machine through code.

How to check the Update location and installed location of click once in user machine, Is it possible to check?

Comment: I need to move from network path to IIS not only the location change

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just change the update URL of the already deployed ClickOnce application due to the security functionality that is built-in into ClickOnce. It checks the update location for the installed application against the URL for the update, and if they don't match, it won't install the new version.

But you can deploy an interim version (an update) to the old location that tells it to look for updates at the new URL. There is a video available here that describes how to this in detail which should be helpful: https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/how-to-move-a-clickonce-deployment/.